# Disable all dates in a calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there a way, I could disable all dates from a calendar? Currently the calendar is constructed as :

```
$('.date-picker-field').datepicker( {
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
});
```

This will display a calendar with all dates enabled. I want to display, with all dates disabled.

Comment: (curious) why do you need that?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I want it to be the calendar's initial state.

Comment: showOtherMonths and selectOtherMonths to false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `beforeShowDay` method and return an array with `false` values:

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay:function(date){
     return [false, ''];
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: Once all dates are disabled, how can I enable only certain date(s) from certain months?